# unable to set environment variable in PHP

Tags: php, environment-variables

here is the code:

```
putenv("LC_ALL=ru_RU.utf8");
print_r($_ENV) . PHP_EOL;
echo getenv('LC_ALL') . PHP_EOL;
```

I get following response:

```
Array (
[USER] => www-data
[HOME] => /var/www
[FCGI_ROLE] => RESPONDER
[QUERY_STRING] =>
[REQUEST_METHOD] => GET
[CONTENT_TYPE] =>
[CONTENT_LENGTH] =>
[SCRIPT_FILENAME] => /var/www/cms/public/index.php
[SCRIPT_NAME] => /index.php
[REQUEST_URI] => /backend/users
[DOCUMENT_URI] => /index.php
[DOCUMENT_ROOT] => /var/www/cms/public
[SERVER_PROTOCOL] => HTTP/1.1
[GATEWAY_INTERFACE] => CGI/1.1
[SERVER_SOFTWARE] => nginx/1.0.2
[REMOTE_ADDR] => 127.0.0.1
[REMOTE_PORT] => 48644
[SERVER_ADDR] => 127.0.0.1
[SERVER_PORT] => 80
[SERVER_NAME] => cmsdev.com
[REDIRECT_STATUS] => 200
[PATH_INFO] => /index.php
[HTTP_HOST] => cmsdev.com
[HTTP_USER_AGENT] => Mozilla/5.0 (
X11; Linux x86_64; rv:5.0
) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/5.0
[HTTP_ACCEPT] => text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
[HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE] => ru,en-us;q=0.7,en;q=0.3
[HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING] => gzip, deflate
[HTTP_ACCEPT_CHARSET] => ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
[HTTP_CONNECTION] => keep-alive
[HTTP_COOKIE] => PHPSESSID=ipsldis425a3pitimet7uehaa7; locale=ru_RU; timezone=%7B%22name%22%3A%22UTC%2B0%22%2C%22offset%22%3A0%7D
[HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL] => max-age=0
)

ru_RU.utf8
```

So - it looks like instead of `$_GET - it prints $_SERVER` and it doesn't contain `LC_ALL`.  Any clues? (`variables_order = "EGPCS"`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It doesn't print `$_SERVER`, it print `$_ENV`. Environment variables are set the web server which is why you see then when you print `$_ENV`. As it says in the [`$_ENV` documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.environment.php), it says:

> An associative array of variables passed to the current script via the
> environment method.
>
> These variables are imported into PHP's global namespace from the
> environment under which the PHP parser is running. Many are provided
> by the shell under which PHP is running and different systems are
> likely running different kinds of shells, a definitive list is
> impossible. Please see your shell's documentation for a list of
> defined environment variables.
>
> Other environment variables include the CGI variables, placed there
> regardless of whether PHP is running as a server module or CGI
> processor.

Those values are set when the script is first executed. When you call `setenv()`, those values are not automatically added to `$_ENV`. You either have to add them manually or use the `getenv()` function.

This was also documented in the [`putenv` documentation comments](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.putenv.php#98540).

Answer (score 1):

Is [safe_mode](http://php.net/manual/en/features.safe-mode.php) enabled? If so, you may be only able to set certain variables. See [this documentation of putenv](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.putenv.php) on php.net.