# PHP getenv() doesn't return all variables, even if they are set and can get directly

Tags: php, nginx

I'm having a problem with PHP `getenv()` function, when I set a variable with `putenv(KEY=VAL)` I can fetch it directly with `getenv(KEY)` but it won't return as part of the array when I call `getenv()` without any key.

```php
<?php

putenv("FOO=BAR");
var_dump(getenv('FOO'))
var_dump(getenv())
```

```
/app/releases/1/public/test.php:4:string 'BAR' (length=3)
/app/releases/1/public/test.php:5:
array (size=52)
  'USER' => string 'apache' (length=6)
  'HOME' => string '/usr/share/httpd' (length=16)
  'HTTP_CONNECTION' => string 'keep-alive' (length=10)
  'HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING' => string 'gzip, deflate, br' (length=17)
  ...
  (more key => values but not 'FOO')
```

I see this note on PHP `getenv()` documentation site:

[image: PHP getenv() Notes]

I'm not sure but if I'm using `php-fpm` which uses `fpm-fcgi`, then this behavior is expected ?

But what confuses me is that if I call the `getenv('KEY')` without setting the 2nd parameter (`local_only`) to true, I **do** get the value.

What I'm missing ? how can I resolve this ?

P.S.:

- I'm running PHP version `7.4.13` with PHP-FPM + NGINX
- I also tried to add `E` to `variables_order` in `php.ini`, but that didn't help
- Same issue: [getenv() doesn't show all variables, even if they are set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58318311/getenv-doesnt-show-all-variables-even-if-they-are-set)

Comment: I'm guessing `getenv(null, $local_only=true)` doesn't work?? From reading the `getenv()` docs, it sounds like expected behavior. BUT the documentation isn't totally clear / is incomplete. IMO, that warning should say something explicit about what happens if there is NOT a value set by the SAPI. It should also comment on using `getenv()` without a key. I'd recommend reporting a documentation bug for getenv. See the 'Report a Bug' link on [getenv docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getenv.php)

Comment: Yes @Reed, i also tried that as well, didn't work. I think because PHP allow `null` to be a key in an array.

Comment: I'm guessing `getenv()` is [like `$_ENV`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6728526/965834) and therefore its return value doesn't change after runtime calls to `putenv`. But this is very poorly documented in any case.